# WebDriver exception on using Winiumdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, winium

I have started learning Winium tool. When running using the below code getting:

```
public class CalcDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        DesktopOptions options=new DesktopOptions();
        options.setApplicationPath("‪C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
        WiniumDriver driver=new WiniumDriver(new URL("http://localhost:9999"), options);
        driver.findElementByClassName("Edit").sendKeys("This is sample test");
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

I'm getting the bellow error:

```
"org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: The given path's format is not supported"
```

Can anyone help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to find the window before trying to access the Edit class.

Here's my C# example:

```
        var dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
        dc.SetCapability("app", @"C:/windows/system32/Notepad.exe");
        var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://localhost:9999"), dc);

        var window = driver.FindElementByClassName("Notepad");
        var edit = window.FindElement(By.Name("Text Editor"));
```